# How to extract mutliple text lines within xml file by using grep and/or sed

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, grep, xml

I am trying to extract some lines within a `<w:t>` tag in front and `</w:t>` tag at the end of the text I want, but im only getting the text within last tags and not the others. How can i do this?

This is the code ive been trying to use:

```
grep '<w:t>' word/document.xml | sed 's/.*<w:t>\(.*)<\/w:t>.*/\1/' | cat > brev.txt
```

as you can see I'm `grep`ing from the `document.xml` file within the word directory and finding the tag within the file and transfering it to a file named `brev.txt`, but it's not working entirely. How do i get all the lines and not just the last line with the tag?

the `document.xml` file is a one line text file, if that makes any difference.

I also tried another code and this gave me everything from the first `<w:t>` tag and including everything within until the last `</w:t>` tag. So alot of extra text within, the following code for that was:

```
grep -o '<w:t>.*</w:t>' word/document.xml | sed 's/\(<w:t>\|<\/w:t>\)//g' > brev.txt
```

Sample file (formatted for readability; the original is a single line)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid wp14">
  <w:body>
    <w:p w14:paraId="35B527D8" w14:textId="4CF0BDCB" w:rsidR="0068138C" w:rsidRDefault="00BF1E48">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Here’s a Word document. It has several sentences.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w14:paraId="4AADFADF" w14:textId="4F49E2CE" w:rsidR="00BF1E48" w:rsidRDefault="00BF1E48">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Most are short.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w14:paraId="608ED30C" w14:textId="2163C420" w:rsidR="00BF1E48" w:rsidRDefault="00BF1E48">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>All are in English.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w14:paraId="0B67C683" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00BF1E48" w:rsidRDefault="00BF1E48">
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00BF1E48">
      <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
      <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
      <w:cols w:space="708"/>
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Comment: Having an example file to test solutions on would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use an XML parser to parse XML. Using the sample document I added to your question,

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//w:t' -n word/document.xml >brev.txt

cat brev.txt
Here’s a Word document. It has several sentences.
Most are short.
All are in English.
```

If you really cannot get hold of an XML parser, but you have GNU `grep`, you could use this pattern. But it's the wrong way to approach the problem

```
grep -oP '(?<=<w:t>).*?(?=</w:t>)' word/document.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and making it better. The sample file was a great idea, thank you.
Thank you for your suggestion! Why is it the wrong way to approach the problem?

Comment: XML doesn't define a physical file layout. At the moment it's all one line, but the XML file would still be perfectly valid if the component `<w:t` was on a different line to its corresponding `>…</w:t>`. In such a situation the XML parser `xmlstarlet` would continue to work but the `grep` would fail (silently)

Comment: Thank you for your time.